# Calling WCF(3.5) with AJAX jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I can't get an ajax call to another server to work. It works local and it works if I do it with c# code or using a program like soapui so I suppose my browser is "blocking" the call. The wsdata below contains a soap envelop. The error message is "400 bad request". Any ideas?

I can't use the web.config setting below since it's not supported.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>


function invokeService() {
    $(document).ready(function() {                      
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          //async: "false",
          url: "service.svc",
          data: wsdata,
          contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "xml",
          //processData: true,
          success: function(result) {
              AjaxSucceeded(result);
          },
          error: AjaxFailed
      });
  });
}
function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
    alert(result);
}
function AjaxFailed(result) {
    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}
```

Update. This works local but not to another server.

I get the message "200 ok" but the response contains what looks like the page that is shown if you paste "servicev.svc" in your browser.

```
function invokeService() {
    $(document).ready(function() {                      
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          //async: "false",
          url: "service.svc",
          data: wsdata,
          contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
          //dataType: "jsonp",
          //processData: true,
          success: function(result) {
              AjaxSucceeded(result);
          },
          error: AjaxFailed
      });
  });
}
function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
    alert(result);
    result();
}

function AjaxFailed(result) {
    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}
```

Comment: Correction: The type in the ajax call is POST.

Answer (score 0):

Set your dataType to jsonp, since you are setting `webHttpBindingWithJsonP` and make sure you pass the json response from service

```
  dataType: 'jsonp'
```

Comment: I'm not using webHttpBindingWithJsonP, that was just from an example. Any other ideas?